# biblatex: automaticallty convert volume numbers from roman to arabic

Tags: biblatex, formatting, number

I've got automatically generated bibtex files which have many long roman volume numbers like LXXXVIII.  This often cause overfull hboxes in the typeset bibliography because they cannot be hyphenated.

Can biblatex be told to automatically convert these to arabic, like 88 in this example?

Comment: Just in case this is also motivated by a worry about sorting of roman numeral volumes, `biber` auto-detects roman numerals in datamodel integer fields and converts them internally automatically to arabic for sorting as real integers. It recognises and converts even Unicode special roman characters like "Ⅵ" (that's one glyph, not two ...)

Answer (score 4):

The `etoolbox` package provides the macro `\rmntonum` that converts roman numerals to arabic. Biblatex allows to declare a field format to modify the contents of a field. Therefore using `\rmntonum` with `\DeclareFieldFormat` results in the required functionality.

To make sure the volume number is still printed correctly when it is not a roman numeral you can use `\ifrmnum` (also from `etoolbox`) and convert only if the volume is actually a roman numeral (and just print the number unconverted otherwise).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{myarticle,
    author={John Doe},
    title={Some Article},
    journal={A Journal},
    volume={LXXXVIII},
    year={2020},
    publisher={Roman Publishing}
}
@article{myotherarticle,
    author={John Smith},
    title={Other Article},
    journal={Some Journal},
    volume={23},
    year={2020},
    publisher={Arabic Publishing}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\ifrmnum{#1}{\rmntonum{#1}}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\cite{myarticle,myotherarticle}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]